# Scheduling a meeting of N people

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list

Problem: There are N people and S slots. Each person has a list of slots in which he is busy.
We have to find an algo to find a slot in which all of them are free.

I already know an algo whose complexity is O(NS). Need a better algo.

You are free to maintain different data-structures dynamically (they will be updated whenever a meeting is scheduled) which can be used to finally find a free slot.

Comment: Can you describe the O(ns) algorithm? Can you elaborate on why you think it is O(ns)? I can't imagine situations where there are millions of people (N large) each with billions of slots (S large) so that O(<ns) would be worth the effort (in the context you describe)...is this a purely academic question? Homework even?

Comment: You might try guessing random slots: it would be O(NS) but there's a chance it would be less.

Comment: The input to your problem isn't really N and S, but the *k* = O(NS) tuples (*n*, *s*) that indicate person *n* is busy during slot *s*. Therefore, you are really looking for an O(*k*) algorithm; that's the best you can do, since it will take that long just to scan the input. Depending on how your O(NS) algorithm works, it could already be optimal.

Comment: If there's a constraint of one person per slot, this is a bipartite matching probelm which is not solvable in the runtime you mentioned

Comment: It is a bipartite graph, but the stated problem is looking for a slot node with 0 neighbors.

Comment: (Remember to accept an answer if you find one acceptable).

Answer (score 2):

Keep a slotcounter for each slot. for each persons busy slot add one to that slots slotcounter; for all peoples busy slots.

Any slotcounter which is still zero after accounting for all peoples busy slots is a a counter for a slot in which all people are free. Probably an O(k) algorithm.

Instead of counting you could set up a bitmask/bitset where person N's bitmask has bit S set in all positions where they are busy. A bitwise OR of all the peoples bitmasks will have zero bits corresponding to all the free slots.

UPDATE:
The way you state the problem, you don't have to track the people just keep an array of slot occupancy indicators. Initially all are marked free; as you go through each persons busy slots mark the appropriate occupancy indicator as busy. When you are done, any of the arrays indicators that are still free is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Algo will work assuming we have a sorted list of slots for each person

1. Now you have N-lists of size S (maximum) each. Merge sort this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm
2. Typical merge sort (using heap) will result in complexity NlogK, where N is the total # of elemets in all 'K' lists. However, if your version, each element in the N-lists are bounded to be between 0 and s-1. Therefore, the complexity is also bounded by S*log(N). Iterating through the N-lists with a heap size of maximum 'N', bounded by S-iterations. Makes sense?

So, overall complexity = N*log(S) + S*log(N)

This is assuming the original list is sorted, else complexity goes up to N(SlogS)

Comment: Surely step 1 is O(N*SlogS). SlogS for each sort done N times.

Comment: You are redefining N in the middle of your solution: first it's the number of people, then it is the number of (person, busy time) pairs.

Comment: According to the link you gave, the complexity of merging N lists with maximum S elements in each is **O(NSlogS)** which is worse than O(NS).
Also, as pointed out by @chepner, you are redefining N in the middle.

Comment: For merge sort using heap, let Ntotal = total # of elements in all lists put together and let there be d - lists. The complexity is indeed O(Ntotal*log(K)). So, you are assuming that the total runtime is O(NSlog(S)) for the problem in hand. This is wrong. In this case, each element in the list is guaranteed to be between 0 and (S-1). Merge sort using heaps involves using 'N' pointers in the heap and incrementing them one at a time. Since the value of each element is bounded, the number of updates is also bounded. Hence the runtime is in fact O(SlogN) as I state and not O(NSlogS)

Answer (score 0):

Generate a bitmask of size S with the bits set for when S is busy. Bitwise OR all bitmasks together, then extract the bit that isn't set.

Answer (score -1):

Bearing in mind that there might well not be a solution, the [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) will provide the closest answer

Comment: The problem is to find a single slot when no one is busy, not to assign each person to a unique slot.

Comment: and if there is no such slot? (You're wasting -1)

Comment: Then the answer is "no such slot". This is a simpler problem than what the Hungarian Algorithm is attempting to solve.